# ElanTech touchpad both keys simultaneously don't work

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I have a huge problem with ElanTech touchpad. Without the ElanTech driver both the keys can be used at the same time(R+L). This is usefull in games like Mafia2 (can't play without it). When I install their driver I get the gestures, scrolling etc. but I can't use both keys at the same time. It is a common problem.

Acer Aspire v3-571G Windows 7 x64

This didn't work at all: Synaptics  15.3.41.5

Is there any universal driver which will give me at least scrolling and simultaneous keys usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded Mouse Generic form Apcom. It is awesome, works fine and finally did, wrong, but did do good, well.

Comment: 2 questions: 1.Where did you find Apcom? 2.what exactly do you mean by "works fine and finally did, wrong, but did do good, well"? -that makes absolutely no sense to me... :o/